# Convert operator from Matlab to R

Tags: r, matlab, operators

I have below code in Matlab:

```
alpha=5.5; beta=3.1; a=0; b=1; c=2.5;
X=0; Y=c; % Initial values
while Y > gamma(alpha+beta)/gamma(alpha)/gamma(beta)...
* X.^(alpha-1).* (1-X).^(beta-1);
U=rand; V=rand; X=a+(b-a)*U; Y=c*V;
end; 
X;
```

and I want to convert to R. This is my attempt (something is wrong in operators):

```
alpha <- 5.5
beta <- 3 .1
a <- 0
b <- 1
c <- 2.5
X <- 0
Y <- c
while(Y > gamma(alpha+beta)/gamma(alpha)/gamma(beta)) 
{
*X.^(alpha-1).*(1-X).^(beta-1) # incorrect line
U=runif(1, 0, 1)
V=runif(1, 0, 1)
X=a+(b-a)*U
Y=c*V
}
print (X)
```

Comment: Error: unexpected '*' in:
"while(Y > gamma(alpha+beta)/gamma(alpha)/gamma(beta)) {
*"

Comment: I don't know what a leading asterisk does in Matlab, (and you are not describing in natural language what you expect)  but in R , an asterisk with no symbol/name is an invalid expression so it fails at the parse phase of evaluation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `beta` had an invalid assignment and you needed the `{` on the same line as the `while`:

```
alpha <- 5.5
beta <- 3.1
a <- 0
b <- 1
c <- 2.5
X <- 0
Y <- c
while (Y > gamma(alpha + beta)/gamma(alpha)/gamma(beta) * X^(alpha - 1) * (1 - X)^(beta - 1)) {
    U <- runif(1, 0, 1)
    V <- runif(1, 0, 1)
    X <- a + (b - a) * U
    Y <- c * V
}
```

Check your code to make sure you are doing what you think you are doing, no assignment is being done on the line after the `while`, the loop kept exiting immediately for me (but running without error) and printing `0` for `X`.

**EDIT:**
Runs correctly now thanks to the nice spot by @Khashaa

Comment: Just code in Matlab return correct answear and if I only get rid of dots in R code then I also return correct answear but with following errors:  
Error: unexpected '*' in:
"while(Y > gamma(alpha+beta)/gamma(alpha)/gamma(beta)){ 
  X=*"

Error: unexpected '}' in "}"

Comment: What I'm saying is that `Y > gamma(alpha+beta)/gamma(alpha)/gamma(beta)` evaluates to `FALSE` in the above code -- so it never even enters the `while` loop. Make sure parenthesis are where they need to be to make sure the order of operations you desire is being executed

Comment: change to `Y >gamma(alpha+beta)/gamma(alpha)/gamma(beta)*X^(alpha-1)* (1-X)^(beta-1);`. Those pesky `...` directs continuation of the expression to the next line.